# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)\sin(\frac 1n)}{n}$ converges or diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My guess is that Abel-Dirichlet I or II may be used to find the convergence, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What about $\left|\frac{\sin(n)\sin(\frac 1n)}{n}\right|\le \left|\frac{\sin(n)}{n^2}\right|\le \frac1{n^2}$?

Comment: How did you find that $|\frac {sin(n)sin(\frac 1n)}{n}|$ $\le$ $| \frac {sin(n)}{n^{2}} |$ ?

Comment: Recall that $|\sin x|\le |x|$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use equiconvergence criteria for absolute convergence of your sum, like:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{\left|\sin(n)\right|\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n}}{\frac{\left|\sin(n)\right|}{n^2}}= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}=1
\end{equation}
The last limit is characteristic one ($\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$). This means that this sum is equiconvergent to the sum:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin(n)|}{n^2}
\end{equation}
This sum is absolutely convergent, meaning that your sum is convergent.

---

Absolute convergence:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{|\sin(n)|}{n^2}}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{equation}

Comment: The criterium is only applicable for the absolute value

Comment: @user My bad, I fixed it. Thank you!